# How to make irregular shape in web to use as container so one part can include content?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want advice to best practices how others get this result. I want to create card like template with irregular shape. 
My idea is to create it from two parts, 1. Head and 2.Content.

1. Head has corner in and corner out radius, I have already put together SVG code. It has fixed height.

```html
<svg>
    <path d="
             M0,60
             Q30,60 30,30
             A30 30 0 0 1 90,30
             Q90,60 120,60
             "/>
</svg>
```

2. Content part is div with basic corner radius. Div because it can easily adapt content. Height of this part is dynamic.

Question is simple: Is this approach good or should I do it differently? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402503/border-curved-css-circle-with-curved-end/50402586#50402586

Comment: Essentially, **you can't**. All HTML elements are rectangular. but you can *fake* the appearance of non-rectangular elements but the content will probably not adapt to the "shape".

Comment: You may like to read this article at css-tricks.com: [Tabs with Round Out Borders](https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)

Comment: Guys, thank you for your time but I only want to know about ideas, how would you approach this. Reading online helps but I was not able to find clear answer if it is good or not to use separate SVG and regular div element to create custom shaped container. I definately want to use SVG, I have tried before this article Tabs with Round Out Borders, but i quickly find out that is too complex. For my needs SVG is simplier.

Comment: Nice job on hand coding the svg path You might want to check out arcs. To answer your question, this is _one way_ to achieve what you want, and a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: Thanks @Ted. Yeah, I have noticed that "Q" command in SVG was more like ellipsed arc. "A" command was better.