# Css invert background color

Tags: html, css

At the moment my css looks like this:

[image]

But I want the inverse of the green border-radius blocks, I want this:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this with the least amount of extra divs and stuff? Here is my code so far:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 35px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  // background-color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

button:after,
button:before {
  background-color: rgb(188, 218, 188);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
}

button:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

button:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button>tab1</button>
  <button>tab2</button>
  <button class="selected">tab3</button>
  <button>tab4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to use svg

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402586/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be using `box-shadow` for the `before` and `after`.
Also you may consider using `pointer-events:none` for the pseudo-elements since you don't want to block the other elements on the nav.

Another solution would be using svg for your buttons.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 35px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

button:after,
button:before {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 1px white;
  pointer-events:none;
}

button:after{box-shadow: -2px 10px 1px white;}

button:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

button:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button>tab1</button>
  <button>tab2</button>
  <button class="selected">tab3</button>
  <button>tab4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a dic contain content text, like this:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 35px;
}

.content {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
button.selected{
  background-color: blue;
}
button.selected .content{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

button.before-selected .content{
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
button.after-selected .content{
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button><div class="content">tab1</div></button>
  <button class="before-selected"><div class="content">tab2</div></button>
  <button class="selected"><div class="content">tab3</div></button>
  <button class="after-selected"><div class="content">tab4</div></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using svg with `background-image` or using the `clip-path` property on `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following property to get the inverted image of the green border radius blocks:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

So your CSS will be like:

```
button:after,
button:before {
  background-color: rgb(188, 218, 188);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Or you can use the following and style it better:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 35px;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  // background-color: green;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button.selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

button:after,
button:before {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

button:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 5px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 5px 0px #000000;
}

button:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 4px 8px 5px -3px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 8px 5px -3px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <button>tab1</button>
  <button>tab2</button>
  <button class="selected">tab3</button>
  <button>tab4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the idea but this doesn't work. It comes out like this: https://i.imgur.com/A9t4bpo.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SVGs on `::before` and `::after` of the tab element. Here's an example:

```css
header {
  background: gray;
}

nav {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.tab {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.tab.selected {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
}

.tab.selected::before,
.tab.selected::after {
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
} 

.tab.selected::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><path d='M 0 10 L 10 10 L 10 0 Q 10 10 0 10 Z' fill='%23ffffff'></path></svg>");
  left: -10px;
}

.tab.selected::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><path d='M 0 10 L 10 10 L 10 0 Q 10 10 0 10 Z' fill='%23ffffff'></path></svg>");
  right: -10px;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <button class="tab">Tab</button>
    <button class="tab selected">Tab</button>
    <button class="tab">Tab</button>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/78875ac508b018a183f0184138a54d24).