# Radius does not adapt in navigationbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, geometry

I am working at a mobile bottom navigation bar. Here is the code I developed:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.mobile_bottombar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 0 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 999;
 }

 .des:before {  /* creates the circle */
  position: absolute;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='24' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path d='M24 10h-10v-10h-4v10h-10v4h10v10h4v-10h10z'/></svg>");
   width: 66px;
   height: 66px;
   top: -45px;
   left: calc(50% - 33px);
   border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #188071;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
 }

 .des {
   border-radius: 6px;
   background: radial-gradient(40px 40px at 50% -11px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 38.5px, #fff);
 }
```

```html
<div class="mobile_bottombar des">
    <div class="bottombar_item" onclick="switchPage(2, 'main', true)">
      <div>
        <span>Sepp</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-right: 20px;" class="bottombar_item" onclick="switchPage(3, 'noteslist', true)">
      <div>
        <span>Depp</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="bottombar_item">
      <div>
        <span>Mepp</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottombar_item" onclick="switchPage(4, 'permission', true)">
      <div>
        <span>Repp</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My problem is that the radius which is cut of the div is another radius than the blue circle. Or maybe there is the other problem which I do not know? Anyway, that looks very weired, because of the different space around the circle. But how to fix that?
~marcelo

Comment: why not a simple red border to the pseudo element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Because the top line of the navigation bar should be rounded a little bit at the edges, where the circle is cut.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Isn't it possible?

Comment: something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50402586/8620333 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try @Temani's comment or if you want to stick to your method continue the reading.

I think that there is no relative way to do it so all you can do is hard-changing the value of the  radial-gradient in the `.des` rule like this:

```css
background: radial-gradient(40px 40px at 50% -11px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 38.5px, #fff);
```

I also advice you to remove the `box-shadow`and replace it with

```css
filter: drop-shadow(0px -2px 1px black);
```

instead, because we can see the shadow crossing the transparent area.

Comment: Thanks it works and looks perfect! But at least one the question? Why the "filter: drop-sha..."?

Comment: because filter: drop-shadow is likely the shadow of the drawn pixels, while box-shadow like it's name is saying is the shadow of the box. Whatever the box will render, box shadow will behave like if the box was a full box... try to change the color of your body to white and you will notice it